# problem related to h5py and create_dataset

Tags: python, version, spyder, h5py, dtype

Maybe the question is dumb, but so far I have not been able to find a solution.
I have been handed a code from other person who was working probably with a different set than mine (e.g. Python 2 instead of 3, etc).
So I have done some small changes to make things work, but I am stuck in a probably simple problem related to h5py.

The part of the code where it crushes looks like:

```
labels_ALL = ['ionic_str','psi0','psi1','psi2','psid','zeta','sig0','sig1','sig2','sigd','sig0_eq','sig1_eq','sig2_eq','sigd_eq','ch_bal_EDL','ch_bal_aq', 'sum_resid']
units_ALL = ['(mol/L)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq)/L)',' ']
for i in range(len(Labels)):
    labels_ALL.append(Labels[i])
    units_ALL.append('(mol/L)')
base.create_dataset('Labels', data=labels_ALL)
base.create_dataset('Units', data=units_ALL)
```

The problem seems to be in base.create_dataset:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\DaniJ\Documents\PostDoc_Jena\Trips, Conf, etc\Sinfonia Workshop\Exercise_1\exercise_1_SINFONIA_for_One\NR_chem_SINGLE_NoEu.py", line 252, in <module>
    base.create_dataset('Labels', data=labels_ALL)

  File "C:\Users\DaniJ\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 136, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\DaniJ\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 118, in make_new_dset
    tid = h5t.py_create(dtype, logical=1)

  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1634, in h5py.h5t.py_create

  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1656, in h5py.h5t.py_create

  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1717, in h5py.h5t.py_create

TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U10')
```

the variable base seems to be a h5py._hl.files.File variable.

Does somebody how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Best regards,
Dani

Comment: The error message (`No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U10')`) refers to Unicode characters which are NOT supported by HDF5 (and h5py). You have to convert Unicode to byte strings before saving. Your code doesn't show the assignment for `labels` values, so I can't reproduce the problem. The code works if I comment out the `for i in range():` loop, and only save the original values of `labels_ALL` and `units_ALL` to the datasets.

Comment: Labels was basically a list of strings such as `Labels = ['H+','Na+','Cl-','OH-','>SOH_x','>SO-_x','>SONa_x','>SOH2+_x','>SOH2Cl_x','>SOH_y','>SO-_y','>SONa_y']`

Comment: Hmmmm...not what I expected for `Labels`. :-( You will get the `dtype('<U10')` error if `Labels` is a NumPy array of strings. Your code works as expected when I add that line (and include the `for` loop). I can reproduce the error if I convert the List to a NumPy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you solve your problem? I'm 99.9% sure it's related to your `Labels` data -- likely it's in a NumPy array instead of a List. I wrote 3 short examples to demonstrate the difference.

1. The first code segment uses a List and successfully creates the
   datasets in file `SO_69900543_1.h5`.
2. The second code segment reproduces your error. It converts the List
   to a NumPy Array then fails when attempting to create the datasets
   in file `SO_69900543_2.h5`. Notice that it gives the same error
   message you encountered: `TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U10')`.
3. The third code segment shows how to modify `numpy.str_` elements to `str` (solves problem in segment #2). Note that the each `Labels` value is converted with `str()` before it is added to `Labels_All`.

Maybe this will help you find (and fix) your problem with Unicode data.

**Code segment 1 (works):**

```
Labels = ['H+','Na+','Cl-','OH-','>SOH_x','>SO-_x','>SONa_x','>SOH2+_x','>SOH2Cl_x','>SOH_y','>SO-_y','>SONa_y']
labels_ALL = ['ionic_str','psi0','psi1','psi2','psid','zeta','sig0','sig1','sig2','sigd','sig0_eq','sig1_eq','sig2_eq','sigd_eq','ch_bal_EDL','ch_bal_aq', 'sum_resid']
units_ALL = ['(mol/L)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq)/L)',' ']

for i in range(len(Labels)):
    labels_ALL.append(Labels[i])
    units_ALL.append('(mol/L)')
with h5py.File('SO_69900543_1.h5','w') as base:
    base.create_dataset('Labels', data=labels_ALL)
    base.create_dataset('Units', data=units_ALL)
```

**Code segment 2 (returns TypeError):**

```
Labels = ['H+','Na+','Cl-','OH-','>SOH_x','>SO-_x','>SONa_x','>SOH2+_x','>SOH2Cl_x','>SOH_y','>SO-_y','>SONa_y']
# Convert Labels List to NumPy array 
# This will trigger the error when creating the dataset
Labels = np.array(Labels)
labels_ALL = ['ionic_str','psi0','psi1','psi2','psid','zeta','sig0','sig1','sig2','sigd','sig0_eq','sig1_eq','sig2_eq','sigd_eq','ch_bal_EDL','ch_bal_aq', 'sum_resid']
units_ALL = ['(mol/L)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq)/L)',' ']

for i in range(len(Labels)):
    labels_ALL.append(Labels[i])
    units_ALL.append('(mol/L)')

for i in range(len(labels_ALL)):   
    print(i, type(labels_ALL[i]), type(units_ALL[i]))

with h5py.File('SO_69900543_2.h5','w') as base:
    base.create_dataset('Labels', data=labels_ALL)
    base.create_dataset('Units', data=units_ALL)
```

**Code segment 3 (works):**

```
Labels = ['H+','Na+','Cl-','OH-','>SOH_x','>SO-_x','>SONa_x','>SOH2+_x','>SOH2Cl_x','>SOH_y','>SO-_y','>SONa_y']
# Convert Labels List to NumPy array 
# This will trigger the error when creating the dataset if not modified
Labels = np.array(Labels)
labels_ALL = ['ionic_str','psi0','psi1','psi2','psid','zeta','sig0','sig1','sig2','sigd','sig0_eq','sig1_eq','sig2_eq','sigd_eq','ch_bal_EDL','ch_bal_aq', 'sum_resid']
units_ALL = ['(mol/L)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(V)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(mol(eq))','(C/m**2)','(mol(eq)/L)',' ']

for i in range(len(Labels)):
    # use str() to convert from 'numpy.str_' to 'str'
    labels_ALL.append(str(Labels[i])) 
    units_ALL.append('(mol/L)')

for i in range(len(labels_ALL)):   
    print(i, type(labels_ALL[i]), type(units_ALL[i]))
    
with h5py.File('SO_69900543_2.h5','w') as base:
    base.create_dataset('Labels', data=labels_ALL)
    base.create_dataset('Units', data=units_ALL)
```

Comment: Thanks that is perfect!!

Comment: Hi Daniel. Glad that helped. If it solved your problem, please check Accepted Answer to indicate it is the solution. Regards.